# How to export vector file in GrassGIS to QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, vector, export

I am using GrassGIS to analyze watershed. I created a stream vector extracted from raster elevation data, how to extract the stream vector file so I can open it using QGIS?

Comment: What is the format of the extracted vector file?

Answer (score 3):

You may export to Shapefile with `v.out.ogr`

Example from the [doc](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.out.ogr.html):

```
v.out.ogr input=lines type=line output=lines.shp
```

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has the ability to connect to GRASS. Follow the links below to integrate the GRASS plugin with QGIS to add GRASS vector data to QGIS and export it into a shapefile or any other format.

https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html

http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/01/setting-up-working-grass-environment-in.html